# SSL/TLS certificate pinning in paho-Eclipse mqtt Android

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, mqtt, paho

I was able to perform MQTT connection to Broker without TLS/SSL certificate using paho{ mqttv3:1.1.0 } Service. However, when I tried pinning SSL certificate in Android it's not working. Please help me in solving the issue. Attaching code for more insight.

**Step 1:  Certificate Conversion**

Converted certificate.pem file to bouncy castle format and stored in the raw folder in Android project.

```
D:\>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\keytool" -import -alias mqtt-broker -file C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\certificate.pem  -keypass ***** -keystore raw_key_file  -storetype BKS -storepass ***** -providerClass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider  -providerpath C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\bcprov-jdk16-1.45.jar
```

**Step 2:  MQTT client Settings**

```
mclientPublisher = new MqttAndroidClient(context, mqttBrokerURL,PublisherClientID, new MemoryPersistence());
    if (null != mclientPublisher) 
       {
        MqttConnectOptions options = null;
        options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1);
        options.setConnectionTimeout(60);
        options.setKeepAliveInterval(120);
        options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        SslUtility.newInstance(context);         
        options.setSocketFactory(SslUtility.getInstance().getSocketFactory
        (R.raw.raw_key_file,"****"));
        options.setCleanSession(true);
       }
```

**Step 3:  SSL UTILITY CLASS**

```
 public class SslUtility {

   private static SslUtility     mInstance = null;
   private Context                mContext = null;
   private HashMap<Integer, SSLSocketFactory> mSocketFactoryMap = new 
   HashMap<Integer, SSLSocketFactory>();




   public SslUtility(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
   }

   public static SslUtility getInstance( ) {
    if ( null == mInstance ) {
            throw new RuntimeException("the first call must be to 
                                        SslUtility.newInstance(Context) ");
    }
    return mInstance;
  }


  public static SslUtility newInstance( Context context ) {
    if ( null == mInstance ) {
        mInstance = new SslUtility( context );
    }
    return mInstance;
  }


 public SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory(int certificateId, String 
                                                      certificatePassword )
    {
     SSLSocketFactory result = mSocketFactoryMap.get(certificateId);
       if ( ( null == result) && ( null != mContext ) ) { 

        try {
          KeyStore keystoreTrust = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");   
          keystoreTrust.load(mContext.getResources().
          openRawResource(certificateId),certificatePassword.toCharArray());
          TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = 
          TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory
                                              .getDefaultAlgorithm());
          trustManagerFactory.init(keystoreTrust);
          SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
          sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), 
                                               new SecureRandom());
          result = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
          mSocketFactoryMap.put( certificateId, result);  
        }
        catch ( Exception ex ) {
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**ERROR/LOGCAT:**

```
 05-18 10:18:55.638 20810-20810/: disconnect method -inside catch block- Error is : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.isConnected()' on a null object reference
```

It seems the MQTT client object is not created.

**Reference:**

[SSL Certificate pinning in Android-MQTT Library[Paho]](http://rijware.com/accessing-a-secure-mqtt-broker-with-android/)

[Paho-eclipse-Forum](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/paho-dev/msg04101.html)

[Developers Android-Google](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl)

[HiveMQ-Mqtt](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-enyclopedia-paho-android-service)

Comment: You did not forget to set the options inside the client , `mclientPublisher.connect(options);` ?  You did not set a try catch arround the `mclientPublisher` creation + connect and log the exception if any ?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you.Can you explain.

Comment: on your code, you have ` if (null != mclientPublisher) { MqttConnectOptions options=...; `  but you never use this options. You should use the `connect` method of client publisher. Also you have  ` catch ( Exception ex ) { }`  So nothing happens if you have exception. Can you log them?  (not just on the part you copy/paste, but everywhere you got that)